# Entity Framework: ObjectSet attach(), entities with multiple relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm battling an Entity Framework problem, completely out of my depth.

In short, I'm hitting an invalid operation exception in the process of attempting to persist an object. I have tracked this back to two entities and the relationships between them. My actual context it too technical to make any sense, so this an equivalent example in a simple domain:

> ### Person
>
> - IdPerson [primary key]
> - Name
>
> ### Organisation
>
> - IdOrganisation [primary key]
> - IdCeo [foreign key => person]
> - IdCfo [foreign key => person]

So, organisation and Person are linked by two many-to-zero-or-one relationships.

- An organisation may have zero or one person as CEO.
- An organisation may have zero or one person as CFO.
- A person may be CEO and/or CFO for zero or more organisations.

I encounter the exception when I attempt to ObjectSet.Attach() an organisation which has the same person acting as both CEO and CFO. It seems that EF tries (and fails) to attach the second person.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
```

The problem does not occur if the CEO and CFO are different people, or if I remove one of the links between Organisation and Person.

Is EF able to handle this model/relationship?
If yes, how can I resolve the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Indicate to Entity Framework which foreign relation is which

```
Organisation

//CEO
public int IdCeo { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("IdCeo")]
public virtual Person CEO { get; set; }


//CFO
public int IdCfo { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("IdCfo")]
public virtual Person CFO { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm dealing with a Model-First scenario. How do I apply the equivalent? Looking at the properties for the links: I have ensured the navigation properties have different names, but the roles have the same names. Is that the problem?